# How do I stop Xpath Parser from auto-calculating my timezone?

Tags: datetime, feeds

When I upload an XML file using the Xpath Parser, Drupal subtracts 8 hours to account for my Pacific Time Zone. This isn't helpful, as it requires for me to convert time in my head.

Is there any way to prevent Drupal from performing this automatic conversion? It works fine when I input nodes manually.

Example:

```
<activity>
    <date>2015-03-09 00:00:00</date>
    <time1>2015-03-09 9:00:00</time1>
    <time2>2015-03-09 10:00:00</time2>
</activity>
```

This returns...

```
Date: March 8th
Time1: 1:00:00
Time2: 2:00:00
```

When I want it to return...

```
Date: March 9th
Time1: 9:00:00
Time2: 10:00:00
```